# Can you load or execute Javascript on a page you link to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, render, execution

I want to link to a page and when the user clicks on the link his username and password are already there for him (a bunch of users will share the same credentials). However where i am linking too i don't control that pages code.

Is it possible to have my javascript execute there after the user clicks the link?

```
$("#link").click(function() {
 alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
 var username = getCookie("username");
    var password = getCookie("password");
    var usernameTextBox = document.getElementById("j_username");
    var passwordTextBox = document.getElementById("j_password");
     usernameTextBox.value = username;
     passwordTextBox.value = password;
 });
```

[See my JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eo38x6po/1/)

so here is the workflow. 
1. a bunch of random users see my page where my javascript loads and they click a link
2. the link brings them to another page where i dont control the code . Could i have javascript from the page in step 1 still run to auto-populate the username and password?

I am thinking so because you could do a ton of malicious stuff with this possibly (the backup plan is to just display the username and credentials below the link and they will have to remember it to log in (or display it in an iframe)).

Are there browsers where I could possibly enable this cross site scripting but only for this one page?

Comment: No you can not control another page via a link. Same Origin Policy

Comment: thanks i figured this would be a browser security feature

Comment: @j08691 could i possibly enable cross site scripting but only for a specific page in a browsers settings?

Comment: If its for a managed kind of users, you can make a browser extension

Comment: Give the user a bookmarklet they can click once on the next page that would fill in said fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can submit a form from your page to an action on another server. This will bypass the login form on the target server all together

```
$("#link").click(function() {
    var username = getCookie("username");
    var password = getCookie("password");
     $("<form action='https://simcontrolcenter.wireless.att.com/provision/j_acegi_security_check' method='POST'>" +
    "<input name='j_username' value='" + username + "'/>" +
    "<input name='j_password' value='" + password +"'/>" +
    "</form>"
  ).submit()
```